# How to query 'history' field in Team Foundation Server (TFS)?

Tags: tfs

I am trying to capture the history of changes when a user story is moved from one iteration to another.

I am trying to query in TFS and using the history field, but don't know what values to put in the value field to capture when a user story is moved to a new iteration.  See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to capture the history of changes when a user story is
>   moved from one iteration to another.

Unfortunately you cannot capture the information as the `History` filed is not the real change history for all actions. It just records the `Discussion History`.

And the work item query is to return work items which matched the given conditions from TFS but not the specific history information.

If you just want to get the real history (iteration change information in your scenario) for a specific work item, then you can call the REST API - [Get Work item revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/wit/revisions?view=tfs-2018)

If you want to filter the work items which have the specific discussion words, then you can specify the words as the value of the `History` field. Reference below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.